# I want the below button code to open a new tab with the URLfetched from a js variable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, buttonclick

can you please help me with the below query?
I have a button code as shown below:

```
    <button type="button" onclick= "location.href=document.getElementById('Text1').value;return false;" class="btn btn-danger">Launch Console</button>
```

Here I have the URL value fetched from a javascript variable. Is there anyway I can open the same in a new tab ? Currently it's loading in the same window/tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: @Thielicious, But here i'm calling the URL value from a **javascript variable**, I'm not sure how to add this to the **window.open** thing...

Comment: @ Rahul Sudha, this is the same thing, it's all explained in this duplicate even with variables. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

<button type="button" onclick= "openInNewTab(urlHere)" class="btn btn-danger">Launch Console</button>
```

Comment: This is from the duplicate link in my comment

Comment: This one worked! I wonder why did i miss to create a separate function!

Comment: Thanks @Daniyal Awan :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id=text type=text>
<button onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('text').value, '_blank');">URL In New Tab</button>
```

Just like I said, read the duplicate closely. And don't use `location.href`.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/by99c8nf/)

Comment: Thanks Thielicios, The sepearte function creation worked!!

Comment: Thanks for the new info too!! :)